# proftpd does not change default group for new files

Tags: permissions, freebsd, ftp

I am Trying to configure ProFTPd to change group for newly created files/directories.

In my config I have this:

```
<Directory /home/*>
  GroupOwner www
</Directory>
```

Which does not seem to work.

All users are added to www group.
Debug shows nothing regarding to a group change.

I'm using FREEBSD 9.0-release.

**EDIT:** I'm willing to try any other FTP server that makes this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep research, I found out that proftpd is not capable of changing a group of newly uploaded file..

However workaround was found:

You need to simply change group for the user's home folder, after which all newly uploaded files will inherit the group from the home folder.

Not much of a solution, but at least something. =)

Comment: ProFTPD **can** change the ownership of upload files; see its [GroupOwner](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#GroupOwner) and [UserOwner](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#UserOwner) directives.

Answer (score 0):

In [`vsftpd`](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) you can do this with the `local_umask=<number>` option. This changes the permissions of an uploaded file for local users. With this option you can thus make sure that group member always have read and write permissions on files and directories.

You need to check the default file permissions (and owner and group, just to be sure!) of uploads and then calculate the correct [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). The default umask that `vsftpd` uses is `077`.

Comment: chmod is not related to this, i need chown